# Problems 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

how can I solve this problem for example: this code:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="NAME">
                     <ItemStyle Width="231px" />

                    <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="CVE_CUST" DataTextField="CVE_CUST" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="/SALES/SALESMONTH.aspx?ID={0}" DataNavigateUrlFields='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CVE_CUST").ToString%>'  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="25px" ControlStyle-CssClass="Objeti" />

                </asp:BoundField>
```

when i try to access the page I see the next bug

```
Línea 60:                          <ItemStyle Width="231px" />
Línea 61:                         
Línea 62:                         <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="CVE_CUST" DataTextField="CVE_CUST" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="/SALES/SALESMONTH.aspx?ID={0}" DataNavigateUrlFields='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CVE_CUST").ToString%>'  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="25px" ControlStyle-CssClass="Objeti" />
Línea 63: 
Línea 64:                     </asp:BoundField>
```

the type System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField not found the property 'HyperLinkField',and thanks for yours comments.

Comment: You can't put a HyperLinkField inside a BoundField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a HyperLinkField inside a BoundField. Use a TemplateField instead.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
   <ItemTemplate>
      PUT HYPERLINK FIELD HERE       
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

See MSDN Documentation [Using TemplateFields in the GridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx).

Comment: thanks my friend I use your recomendation and my code looks like:  <asp:TemplateField >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <a href='<%# "/Ventas/repArchivoPersonalInicio.aspx?Prospecto=" & Eval("CVE_CLIENTE").ToString %>' class="Texto" id="liga" runat="server"><%# Eval("CUSTOMER")%></a>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle Width="230px"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

Answer (score 0):

Finally i resolve my problem, My code is show below:

```
                <asp:TemplateField >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a href='<%# "/Sales/repSales.aspx?ID=" & Eval("CVE_CUST").ToString %>' class="Texto" id="liga" runat="server"><%# Eval("CUSTOMER")%></a>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="230px"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```